# How to customize responsive columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a place to customize responsive columns in Twitter Bootstrap like it here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @user. Could you provide a more detailed explanation about what is your problem? It's very difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Anyway @user, you can customize the variables in the original code (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) and then compile LESS to generate a customized CSS code.

Comment: I downloaded the zip of bootstrap-master but I do not know what to do and how compile LESS.

Comment: There are some instructions of how to compile it inside the link.